# Maven not adding JAR to eclipse Project

Tags: java, eclipse, maven

I am facing a problem again with maven. In my JSP page I want to upload a file and adding some input text fields. Tp process with that I am adding cos.jar for `MultipartRequest` class

Here is my pom

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>servlets.com</groupId>
    <artifactId>cos</artifactId>
    <version>05Nov2002</version>
</dependency>
```

When I run `mvn compile` or `mvn eclipse:eclipse` it is downloading the JAR to maven local repository. But not adding to the eclipse project. What is the problem?

Comment: In the project explorer do you see Maven Dependencies anywhere?

Comment: @KevinBowersox I don't get you. In project explorer, under referenced libraries, I cannot see the JAR.

Comment: Under your Maven Dependencies?  Do you see Maven Dependencies anywhere in project explorer? If not see my answer.

Comment: I cannot see maven dependency under Project Explorer. Let me check your answer

Comment: But other JARs are adding to eclipse.

Comment: You need to be more specific.  Other jars as in other jars pulled in by maven that you do not want to include?

Comment: No. I mean other JARs(like spring, commons-logging..) that I specified in pom.xml are downloading and adding to the eclipse project. But this JAR not adding to eclipse project

Answer (score 6):

Make sure the Maven Dependencies are on the build path and included in the deployment assembly.

**Add Maven Dependencies to Build Path**

> Project Properties > Java Build Path > Libraries > Add Library > Maven
>   Dependencies

**Add Maven Dependencies to Deployment**

> Project Properties > Deployment Assembly > Add > Java Build Path
>   Entries > Maven Dependencies

Comment: +1 for mentioning the basic instructions to follow while building maven in eclipse.

Comment: @András Glad to hear!

Comment: Does not work for eclipse 4.4, 4.5. Add Library > Maven Dependencies comes to a page  that says "use maven project settings to configure maven dependency resolution" !! But I have already done that. There is a missing maven related eclipse plugin prob'ly.

Answer (score 3):

Do you use m2eclipse? When you say eclipse project, do you mean the view or eclipse project settings? Try on the eclipse project `Maven` → `Update project`.

Answer (score 0):

can you please check the above entry is there in the file .jsdtscope under settings folder. If not please add and refresh the project.